# Probability — Survivor game

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a recent season of the TV show Survivor, 16 players were split into two teams of 8 players each. One player on each team was randomly given a secret idol which would not have a power until later in the game. The teams then competed in challenges every few days with each team equally likely to win each challenge. The losing team would then lose a random player. What is the probability (as a fraction) that, when 10 players remain, both players with a secret idol are still in the game?

Is there an easy way to solve this without exhaustively considering the outcomes?

Comment: I think the only outcomes you need is the final team sizes. You don't need to know how the teams got to that size. You can find for example the probability of the final team sizes being 6+4. Given those team sizes, you can find the probability of both idols still being there. So you can use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) over the various team sizes to get your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Considering all the cases for final team sizes**

**2 - 8:**

The probability of any final team size always has the factor of $\frac{1}{2^6}$ due to the probability of one team member leaving being $\frac{1}{2}$.

$$\rightarrow \frac{2}{8} \cdot \frac{8}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{2^6} = \frac{1}{256}$$

**3 - 7:**

However an additional factor is required for this case to account for the different combinations members can be removed from each team to result in this final team size.

$$\rightarrow \binom{6}{1}\cdot\frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{7}{8} \cdot 
\frac{1}{2^6} = \frac{63}{2048}$$

**4 - 6:**

$$\rightarrow \binom{6}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{8} \cdot \frac{6}{8} \cdot 
\frac{1}{2^6} = \frac{45}{512}$$

**5 - 5:**

$$\rightarrow \binom{6}{3}\cdot\frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{5}{8} \cdot 
\frac{1}{2^6} = \frac{45}{512} = \frac{125}{1024}$$

The cases of **2 - 8**, **3 - 7**, **4 - 6** can happen twice because the teams can be swapped. These outcomes can be multiplied by a factor of 2 to account for that.

**Summing up every outcome:**

$$\frac{2}{256} + \frac{126}{2048} + \frac{90}{512} + \frac{125}{1024} = \boxed{\frac{47}{128}}$$